# Stop jQuery Slider moving below elements on Responsive site

Tags: jquery, slider, move

Using the jQuery slideDown/Up function, all my content below the slider moves up and down. I only want content within the slider to move.

Setting a fixed height with overflow:hidden or using position:absolute are not ideal as this is a responsive site.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Here's some stripped down code if helpful. Thanks!

```
    <div class="videos">
    <ul class="vidnav nav-font">    
    <a class="speaker1-mini" href="#"><li>Animation</li></a>
    <a class="speaker2-mini" href="#"><li>Demo Reel</li></a>
    <a class="speaker3-mini" href="#"><li>Business Video</li></a>
</ul>

<section class="gallery">
    <div class="speaker1-content">111</div>
    <div class="speaker2-content">222</div>
    <div class="speaker3-content">333</div>
    </section>
    </div>

    $("[class*='-content']").hide();
    $("[class*='-mini']").hide();
    $("[class*='-expand']").hide();

    $('[class^="speaker"]').click(function () {
        //Hide it all! retract on click
        $("[class*='-content']").slideUp();
        $("[class*='-mini']").slideDown();
        var divClass = $(this).attr("class").split("-")[0] + "-content";
        $("." + divClass).slideDown("slow");
    });
```